# Python regex's fuzzy search doesn't return all matches when using the or operator

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search

For example, when I use

```
regex.findall(r"(?e)(mazda2 standard){e<=1}", "mazda 2 standard")
```

, the answer is ['mazda 2 standard'] as usual.

But when I use

```
regex.findall(r"(?e)(mazda2 standard|mazda 2){e<=1}", "mazda 2 standard")
```

or

```
regex.findall(r"(?e)(mazda2 standard|mazda 2){e<=1}", "mazda 2 standard", overlapped=True)
```

, the output doesn't contain 'mazda 2 standard' at all. How to make the output contain 'mazda 2 standard' too?

Comment: Could you explain what you expect the regex to match besides "mazda 2 standard"? I'm asking because the rest of the pattern looks syntactically invalid to me. I'm surprised it matches anything at all.

Comment: Hi. In the latter case, I would like to see ['mazda 2', 'mazda 2 standard']. There is no syntax error when I run these, but please tell me if I probably write something wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah my bad, I did not notice that you are using `regex` rather than `re`. So the pattern should be correct. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

See [PyPi regex documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

> By default, fuzzy matching searches for the first match that meets the given constraints. The `ENHANCEMATCH` flag will cause it to attempt to improve the fit (i.e. reduce the number of errors) of the match that it has found.
>   
>   The `BESTMATCH` flag will make it search for the best match instead.

You get `mazda 2` with your code because this match contains no errors.

So, use the `BESTMATCH` flag (an inline modifier option is `(?b)`):

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r"(?be)(mazda2 standard|mazda 2){e<=1}", "mazda 2 standard")
['mazda 2 standard']
>>>
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I tested it in Python 2.7.9. Regex lib version: 2016.01.10