# regex non greedy fuzziness

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a target word in a text string, allowing for fuzziness

```
import regex
text = 'hello this is a test'
pattern = '(test){e<=2}'
```

however, `regex.search(pattern, text, regex.IGNORECASE)` returns 'a test', how can I made it match only the exact pattern (when possible) and not start matching earlier using the allowed fuzziness ?

Comment: You need to use `(test){e<=2}` to apply the quantifier to the whole word and use `regex.ENHANCEMATCH`. With `test{e<=2}`, the quantifier is only applied to `t`

Comment: Sorry, I did include the parenthesis on my hand but forgot to add them here

Comment: Ok, the answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048183/python-regexs-fuzzy-search-doesnt-return-all-matches-when-using-the-or-operato/43048502#43048502 `regex.ENHANCEMATCH` is already yielding the expected result, as is `regex.BESTMATCH`. [Online demo](https://rextester.com/CMYVC78512).